# Layout not shown as required using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working with tkinter in python and require to build a simple GUI with labels and buttons like this :

[image]

But I am facing two problems . First is I am getting buttons at top instead of below the timer. Second thing is I am having a list of buttons so instead of writing all four buttons positions explicitly can there be some better way.

Currently my output is :

[image]

My code is :

```
from Tkinter import *
import json
import tkMessageBox


class ProgramGUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        master.title('QuizBox')
        master.update()
        master.minsize(350, 150)
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        questionText = StringVar()
        Label(master, textvariable=questionText,
              justify=CENTER, wraplength=200).pack()
        questionText.set("Question text goes here")

        timer = IntVar()
        Label(master, textvariable=timer, justify=CENTER, fg="blue").pack()
        timer.set("10")

        buttonList = []
        buttonList.append("Answer 1")
        buttonList.append("Answer 2")
        buttonList.append("Answer 3")
        buttonList.append("Answer 4")
        # ADD FOUR BUTTONS HORIZONTALLY

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        answer1 = Button(self, text="Answer 1")
        answer1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        answer2 = Button(self, text="Answer 2")
        answer2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        answer3 = Button(self, text="Answer 3")
        answer3.grid(row=0, column=2)
        answer4 = Button(self, text="Answer 4")
        answer4.grid(row=0, column=3)

        score = IntVar()
        Label(master, textvariable=score, justify=CENTER).pack()
        score.set("Score: 0")


root = Tk()
gui = ProgramGUI(master=root)
gui.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is to move `self.pack()` so that it occurs after you grid your buttons, but before you pack the final label.

```
    answer4.grid(row=0, column=3) 

    self.pack()

    score = IntVar()
```

Now your buttons will appear below the timer and above the score.

[image]

Incidentally, you can use a `for` loop to create your buttons with fewer lines of code.

```
    timer.set("10")

    #ADD FOUR BUTTONS HORIZONTALLY
    buttonList = ["Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4"]
    self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
    for i, value in enumerate(buttonList):
        self.columnconfigure(i, pad=3)
        Button(self, text=value).grid(row=0, column=i)

    self.pack()
```

Comment: Now suppose am having a function named modifyQuestion() and want to modify text of label containing questionText  what should i do. ? Whenever I call modifyQuestion() after score.set("Score: 0") my program crashes. Please help.

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I added new question for it..:)

Answer (score 1):

If you organize your code to reflect the structure of the UI, the solution becomes much easier to visualize.

When I look at your design, I see four clearly defined rows -- the question, the timer, the row of buttons, and a score. If it were me, I would create a separate frame for each row, and stack the rows one on top of each other with pack.

My assumption is that the question is the one row that may change size, since some questions may be short and some may be long.

For example:

```
questionFrame = Frame(self, ...)
timerFrame = Frame(self, ...)
buttonFrame = Frame(self, ...)
scoreFrame = Frame(self, ...)

questionFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
timerFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
scoreFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

By organizing your code like this, and grouping all `pack` statements for a given container together, it becomes much easier to visualize the UI. Once you get these four areas managed properly, you can do whatever you want inside each frame without affecting what is happening in other frames.

You can go a step further and make a class or function to define each section, so you don't have a whole bunch of widgets being defined at the same time. For example:

```
class QuestionFrame(tk.Frame):
    <all the code to implement the question frame>
class ButtonFrame(tk.Frame):
    <all the code to implement the row of buttons>
...
questionFrame = QuestionFrame(...)
buttonFrame = ButtonFrame(...)
...
```

One function or one class per main area of the UI makes the code much easier to manage.

Comment: @BryanOaakley Now suppose am having a function named modifyQuestion() and want to modify text of label containing questionText what should i do. ? Whenever I call modifyQuestion() after score.set("Score: 0") my program crashes. Please help.